# How to create a loop to compare (table) variables within same dataframe?

Tags: r, loops

I've got a dataframe with 706 variables, they are basically two identical dataframes merged together so there's 353 colnames which end with ".x" and the other 353 end ".y".

I want to create a loop which will compare whether the two respective variables ("varible1.x" and "variable1.y") are identical.

If I were to do it manually, I'd have to write 353 times (for each pair of variables) the following code:

```
table(ds$variable.x == ds$variable.y)
```

The results would then be logical, ie.: x n(obs) TRUE/FALSE.

I'd like to know how I can write a loop so that I don't have to write the same thing hundreds of times.

Comment: Hi! please add an example, so we can test our solutions. You can build a simple fake example where you have just 4/5 columns per `data.frame`. It's possible that you won't even need a loop for this.

Comment: I have worked out another possible way of doing it but it's still not working.

#add old and new suffixes
ds_Old <- col_names(ds_Old, 3, ncol(ds_Old), "old", "_")
ds_New <- col_names(ds_New, 3, ncol(ds_New), "new", "_")

#merge dataframes by id
ds_Merge <- merge(ds_Old, ds_New, by = 'id')

#extract list of names to subset
old <- names(ds_Old)
new <- names(ds_New)

#create function to compare
compare <- function(x) { table(x[, old] == x[, new])}

#extract results
results <- lapply(ds_Merge, compare)

last line of code gives: Error in x[, old] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Please include this by edit in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have both previous data.frames prior to the merge, intacts:

```
ds1 <- iris # dummy first data.frame
ds2 <- iris # dummy second data.frame

ds <- merge(ds1, ds2, by = 'Species') # dummy merged data.frame

variables <- intersect(names(ds1), names(ds2))
variables <- variables[!variables %in% names(ds)] # all columns you want to test

store_results <- list() # to store results

for(i in variables){
  var.x <- paste0(i, '.x') # the variables you want to compare followe by .x
  var.y <- paste0(i, '.y') # the variables you want to compare followe by .y

  store_results[[i]] <- table(ds[, var.x] == ds[, var.y]) # comparing
}
```

Given that the merge generates a lot of duplicates, the result is as follows

```
> store_results
$Sepal.Length

FALSE  TRUE 
 6924   576 

$Sepal.Width

FALSE  TRUE 
 6708   792 

$Petal.Length

FALSE  TRUE 
 6682   818 

$Petal.Width

FALSE  TRUE 
 5806  1694
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, however, I get the following error:  Error in Ops.factor(ds[, var.x], ds[, var.y]) : level sets of factors are different

Comment: rewrite your question with a sample of your data and exactly what you are doing, it will be easier to solve the issue